# Jars With same top level name

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am importing a jar, that is dependent on another jar.  Our app needs to sue classes from both jars.  The problem is that both jars have the same top level name. Only the first jar file gets searched.

example:

```
org.pillowcastle:aaa
    org
        pillowcastle
            apache
            bcpg
            openstuff

org.pillowcastle:bbb
    org
        pillowcastle
            axx
            jce
            math
```

when I try to import org.pillowcastle.jce, the import fails, because only org.pillowcastle:aaa is being read.  I'm guessing that when two jars have the same name, only the firs one is utilized.

We are using SpringBoot, Java, IntelliJ, and Maven.  What is the best solution to be able to import and use files from the second jar file?

Thanks.

Comment: What does _top level name_ mean?  The file system name?

Comment: org.pillowcastle

I can import org.pillowcastle.apache, org.pillowcastle.bcpg, and or.pillowcastle.openstuff.  None of the classes in org.pillowcastle:bbb are visible to my application.

Comment: Are you using a module descriptor (`module-info.java`)?

Comment: no, module descriptors are not being used.